MPAndroidChart: unwanted spacing between XAxis and data line in case of dataset has 0f in yaxis value

unwanted space between dataset and xAxisLine if dataset has 0 value.
private fun getData() = arrayListOf(
BarEntry(0f, 10f),
BarEntry(1f, 13f),
BarEntry(2f, 0f), // if I increase this value then everything working fine.
BarEntry(3f, 45f),
BarEntry(4f, 17f),
BarEntry(5f, 72f),
BarEntry(6f, 80f)
)


Did you try setting the y axis minimum to 0?
